# Swapping root directory of a web server

Tags: web-server, mod-rewrite, wordpress, root

One of the clients that I maintain requests a website redesign, we do all the work in a subfolder /newsite/ and they intend to make it live this instant. The /newsite/ is made in wordpress and from my understanding WP keeps all the URL's as they were initially created. Would it be easier to just create the new root dir at /newsite/ or move all contents of the root to /oldsite/ and move /newsite/ to the root?

Please advise the best route, i.e. mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, WordPress has very good documentation:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

If i understood well, why cannot you just change the documentroot?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot

Comment: Good idea, however I do not have access to the apache config file, as it is not hosted under myself.

Answer (score 0):

For these sorts of applications, when running on Linux, I have just created a symbolic link for the root directory in the past.  Then when it is time to switch I just change where the symbolic link points.